# How can I export a structure in a callback in an upper scope?

Tags: c

I have a callback called by a shared library.
I'd like to export a struct `result` to a different scope via `param`:

```
int process(int* result, void* param){
    param = result;
}

// should be hidden by the lib, I only have the definition but for the test, here is it.
int hiddenFunc(int (*f)(int*, void*), void* param){
    int cc = 155;
    f(&cc, param);
}

int main() {
    int *scopeint = NULL;
    hiddenFunc(&process, scopeint);
    printf("scopeint should point to cc and be 155 : %d", *scopeint);
}
```

Why `scopeint` doesn't point to `cc` at the end of the main function?

Comment: You mean like passing a `**` so the callback can "return" a value ?

Comment: I edited in an easier way.

Comment: process() assigns a pointer to a pointer. I shouldn't need **. `scopeint` should have the same address as `cc`

Comment: Even if you successfully change this code (you need some more &s and more *s as people have noted), setting a pointer to a stack variable is going to end in problems anyway.

Comment: Understood, as said, the hiddenFunc is hidden. For the question, I defined it as a stack variable. I believe the var is malloc'd in the lib and freed when I call an `exit()`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scopeint` doesn't point to `cc` at the end of the `main` because you never assigned anything to `scopeint` after initializing it to `NULL`.

If you want a function to modify a variable in the caller, you will need to pass a pointer to it.

```
hiddenFunc(&processCallback, &scopeint);

*(int**)param = result;
```

Generally speaking, you could also return the new value and let the caller modify it for you.

```
scopeint = hiddenFunc(&processCallback);
```

Note that you are trying to set `scopeint` to a pointer to a variable that no longer exists after `hiddenFunc` returns. If you want to "return" a pointer, you will need to place the returned value on the heap instead of using automatic storage.

Altogether, this presents three solutions depending on which of the three functions does the allocation of the `int`.

```
int process(int* result, void* param){
    int *r = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *r = *result;
    *(int**)param = r;
}

int hiddenFunc(int (*f)(int*, void*), void* param){
    int cc = 155;
    f(&cc, param);
}

int main(void) {
    int *scopeint;
    hiddenFunc(&process, &scopeint);
    printf("scopeint should point to cc and be 155 : %d", *scopeint);
    free(scopeint);
}
```

or

```
int process(int* result, void* param){
    *(int**)param = result;
}

int hiddenFunc(int (*f)(int*, void*), void* param){
    int *cc = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *cc = 155;
    f(cc, param);
}

int main(void) {
    int *scopeint;
    hiddenFunc(&process, &scopeint);
    printf("scopeint should point to cc and be 155 : %d", *scopeint);
    free(scopeint);
}
```

or

```
int process(int* result, void* param){
    *(int*)param = *result;
}

int hiddenFunc(int (*f)(int*, void*), void* param){
    int cc = 155;
    f(&cc, param);
}

int main(void) {
    int scopeint;
    hiddenFunc(&process, &scopeint);
    printf("scopeint should point to cc and be 155 : %d", scopeint);
}
```

Comment: `test` is `scopeint` now. It's already a pointer and the hiddenFunc is expecting a pointer, not a pointer of pointer.
I want to assign the address of cc in my pointer.

Comment: The name doesn't matter, and a pointer is a pointer even if it points to a pointer.